# Adding strings to list during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, updatepanel

I have something like this....

```
switch (PostBackControlParentId)
            {
                case "":
                    SearchResults.InnerText = "Sorry. There was an Error.";
                    break;
                case "GamesTabUpdatePanel":
                    Var_Games_Platform = PlatformDropdown.SelectedValue;
                    Var_Games_Rating = Convert.ToDecimal(Games_RatingTextBox.Text);
                    Var_Games_Developer = DeveloperDropdown.SelectedValue;
                    Var_Games_Publisher = PublisherDropdown.SelectedValue;
                    Var_Games_Year = Convert.ToInt16(YearDropdown.SelectedItem.Value);
                    if (Games_OnlyAvailableCheckBox.Checked)
                    {
                        Var_Games_AvailableOnly = true;
                    }

                    foreach (ListItem Genre in Games_GenreList.Items)
                    {
                        if (Genre.Selected)
                        {
                            SearchResults.InnerText = SearchResults.InnerText + Genre.ToString();
                            Var_Games_Genres.Add(Genre.Value.ToString());**///The line of interest........**
                        }
                    }
                    //Get Query Data..
                    //Pass to SQL
                    //Get DataSet
                    //WriteStuff.
                    break;
                case "MoviesTabUpdatePanel":
                    break;
                case "EpisodesTabUpdatePanel":
                    break;
                case "TVShowsTabUpdatePanel":
                    break;
            }
```

Now, when I don't do the

Var_Games_Genres.Add(Genre.Value.ToString());**///The line of interest........**

The UpdatePanel displays exactly what i want..(List of Selected Game Genres in a Checkboxlist named Games_GenreList.
But when I add the following line
Var_Games_Genres.Add(Genre.Value.ToString());**///The line of interest........**
it doesn't change anything on the updatepanel.
And I also get this on the console of google chrome ....

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ScriptResource.axd:847
Error$create ScriptResource.axd:847
PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerServerError ScriptResource.axd:766
PageRequestManager$_parseDelta ScriptResource.axd:1653
PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted ScriptResource.axd:1414
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd:628
(anonymous function) ScriptResource.axd:4338
raise ScriptResource.axd:7429
WebRequest$completed ScriptResource.axd:7433
XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange ScriptResource.axd:6857
```

I really have no idea what's going wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Try refreshing your update panel

Comment: I tried Updatepanel.update();
But no use.

Comment: please check Var_Games_Genres has a instance, meaning did you created it using List Var_Games_Genres = new List();

Comment: Thanks. That's so dumb of me. I created Var_Games_Genres = null;
That totally fixed it. thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List Var_Games_Genres = new List();
```

before the switch case